# Shopify liquid, add multiple products to cart

Tags: shopify, liquid

So I used shopify liquid to add a collection page, in this collection page, there is multiple products. A button named "Add all" will add all products from this collection to shopping cart when click.

How can I achieve this in shopify liquid language? Or how many way we can do this?

Also, when I tried to use this from the official doc

```
jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', {
                quantity: 1,
                id: 10911378372,
                properties: {
                    'First name': 'Caroline'
                }
            }).done(function() {
                console.log("second success");
            })
            .fail(function(err) {
                if(err.statusText !== 'OK'){
                    console.log("error", err);
                }
            })
            .always(function() {
                console.log("finished");
            });
```

even the statusText is Ok, it falls into the fail block and I don't know why.

Comment: Look into Shopify AJAX API, mainly this part: https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api#update-cart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for add multiple items to cart is neccesary a recursive loop.

I did a code for this issue, feel free for use:
[github link](https://gist.github.com/mig1098/1bd84583e73e2ff737c9eece25738939)

the sample is in the `begin` function:

```
    //IF PROPERTIES IS EMPTY ONLY SET FALSE
    MGUtil.data = [
        {"id":"12345","qty":2,"properties":{"data1":"1"}},
        {"id":"34567","qty":3,"properties":{"data2":"1"}},
        {"id":"67892","qty":1,"properties":{"data3":"1"}},
        {"id":"23456","qty":6,"properties":false}
    ]; // ADD 4 ITEMS
    MGUtil.total  = MGUtil.data.length;
    MGUtil.action = 'add';
    MGUtil.recursive();//EXECUTE
```

Comment: thanks for your logic. but when I used your code, here is the error from console. 

Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Comment: on `ajaxpost` function change `async:false` to true,

Answer (score 1):

You would actually do this with a set of AJAX calls. You can only add one item to the cart at a time. See the [AJAX API](https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api#shopify-ajax-api-reference) help.

Then you'd use .liquid to get the default variant id for each displayed product either into a list or, what I generally do, as something like:

```
<div data-variant="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant }}">
  ...
</div>
```

see: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/product#product-selected_or_first_available_variant to see if that would be sufficient

and then your button script would gather the variant ids and add them one-by-one to the cart.

There is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510053/jquery-post-success-callback-is-not-getting-executed/34516353#34516353) of adding an item to the cart with JQuery